# Linux text editor: Pretty. Fast. Powerful. Easy to pick up

Tags: linux, text-editor

Looking for a linux text editor.  I can fumble my way through emacs a little but only really know the basics.  I liked TextMate on OSX but thought it was a bit weak at times (maybe I just didn't learn it well enough).  I don't know if emacs or vim are worth it since I'll still mostly program in eclipse.

- Syntax highlighting
- Themeing support.  I'd like something like sunburst if possible.
- Hopefully don't have to think in a different way when I use it versus other programs.  i.e. I don't think I want to learn all the shortcuts for emacs/vi. (If I were to be sold on this route I'd need something to help me get up to speed quickly and hopefully something in app that helps discover functionality as I go).  Cream might be a go here but I don't know what I'm missing if I do that.
- Mouse usage (text selection, cursor placement, etc)
- doesn't look awful (yes aesthetics do matter to me).
- Auto-formatting support
- Light-weight
- Easily callable from the command line.

Comment: Your question title looks more like an advertisement than a question.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the task at hand.

I've been using Geany to write scripts, it has basic IDE functions, good syntax highlighting etc.

Comment: +1 to Geany though, one of my colleagues uses it and it looks really decent.

Comment: +1 to Geany, it is mostly awesome, but has a few missing features (or broken features such as split screen)

Comment: +1 for Geany - looks good is easy to use and is fast (except some small bug with certain themes

Answer (score 2):

+1 for vim. The learning curve can be a bit steep, but vimtutor can help you a lot.

Once you get accustomed to it you'll wonder how you lived without it.

Answer (score 1):

gEdit. Has a bunch of plugins and has support for vi bindings.  I think it meets all of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) for big projects. It's possible to create macros, key-bindings for commands and snippets through an easy-to-use interface. And there's a good syntax highlight support for most languages too.

A second choice would be [geany](http://www.geany.org/Main/About). It's faster and simple, useful for the most cases where you just want to edit a single file or a small project.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to learn vim or emacs, then print yourself the [vim](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/qrc/vim%20quick%20reference%20card.pdf) or [emacs](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~joanne/emacsRC2.pdf) quick reference card.

In fact, I'd recommend learning vim or emacs even if you wind up mostly using a more modern editor simply because they exist when nothing else does.

I personally prefer vim because many vim commands match sed and perl commands, definitely consider vim if you use these often.  And you should obviously pick emacs if you like lisp.

There was an issue with bash's vi mode in which it ignored the arrow keys for ages, which forced people into using vim for editing and emacs mode in bash, but now `set -o vi` works correctly in bash.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Vim - it's my all time favorite editor and the more I learn about the shortcuts and use more plugins and stuff, I would never go to another editor :) Although in my spare time I have started dabbling with Emacs, just for the kicks. Vim essentially has two modes - normal and insert, so you switch back and forth between them. In the insert mode you type, in the normal mode you do magic with the shortcuts. The power is awesome and after a while it becomes intuitive, and you start finding that you just did a keyboard combination and it worked as you expected, although you never specifically read about this combination. E.g. delete till the character 'x' before the current position of the cursor = Esc+d+T+x (when you only knew that Esc+d+t+x (small t) works in the forward mode.

Simpler ones on Linux are nano, pico, and gEdit :)